# javascript xmlhttp response works is odd

Tags: javascript, response, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

onreadystatechange() gets called 3 times. the second time 'results-div'.innerhtml is set to  'empty' and then erased on the last call to the function. also, does jquery handle ajax browser compatibility?

```
function loaddata(){ 
        var res = new XMLHttpRequest();
        res.onreadystatechange=function(){
            alert('change'); //for debug
            if(res.readyState == 4 && res.status==200){
                document.getElementById('results-div').innerHTML = res.response;
                }
            else{
                alert('nothing'); //for debug
                document.getElementById('results-div').innerHTML = '<p> empty </p>';
                }
        }
        res.open('GET', '?search=' + value);
        res.send();
}
```

'results-div'.innerHTML erased on the last call. if(must be true) 'results'.innerHTML = res.response = ''

Comment: It should be `res.responseText` or `res.responseXML` depending on the MIME type of the response

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest.response` depends on `XMLHttpRequest.responseType`, which you did not set.

Comment: changed to responseText, still does not work correctly @devnull69

Comment: did you check the browser development tools of your choice (Chrome dev tools, Firebug etc) to find out what is actually going on with the request?